# Sonar Qube LOC less than expected

Tags: c#, javascript, sonarqube

I am running a Sonar analysis on mixed C# / JS projects and recently upgraded to 4.2. One of the projects worked without a hitch, but the other has had a dramatic decress in lines of code.

The LOC come out at around 6000, and are made up of files in just two folders. The dashboard however says that I have 916 files in 133 directories and if I navigate to them it will show me the code.

[image: Sonar Dashboard]

I have checked the exclusion list and there is nothing in there to warrant not showing the majority of my code. I think the biggest clue is that the files are included but the analysis is not being run on them, but I just cant figure out why. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found the issue. The SonarQube plugin for c# does not support the multi language functionality yet. Only the js files are being analysed, but the rest are shown.